# URL Parameters for API

Tags: api, url, parameters

I am trying to connect to this API endpoint, some parameters such as `roomTypes` and `addOns` require more parameters inside them. What should the URL be like?

Here is what I am trying, unsuccessfully:

`https://api.lodgify.com/v2/quote/308200/?arrival=2020-10-02&departure=2020-10-07&propertyId=308200&roomTypes=[Id=373125, People=5]&addOns=[]`

See image of Documentation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format of parameters are as following:

```
https://api.lodgify.com/v2/quote/{PropertyID}?arrival={DATE}&departure={DATE}&roomTypes[0].id={RoomID}&roomTypes[0].people={PEOPLE}
```

Comment: Can I ask where you ended up finding this information? I spent ages looking through the docs for this, was going to tell them to add it if it's not in there

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have *space* (white space) between Id and People in your URL, an URL must not contain a literal space

Comment: Thanks, I am afraid that is not the issue tho. `https://api.lodgify.com/v2/quote/308200/?arrival=2020-10-07&departure=2020-10-14&propertyId=308200&roomTypes=[Id=3731256&People=10]&addOns=[]` does not work either.